# Using nested key paths in KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

Suppose i want to observe a property named '`isEnabled`' on a property named 'controller' on self. AFAIK i have two options for installing such kind of observation:
1.     `[self.controller addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isEnabled" options:0 context:nil];`    
2.     `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"controller.isEnabled" options:0 context:nil];`

I noticed the practical difference between the two approaches - on the second approach i will get a notification if the 'controller' object on self was replaced while with the first approach I will be notified only when '`isEnabled`' property is changed on the same instance on which I installed the observation.

My question is where the hell is this documented if at all? I know it works but should I use it? 
I could not find any mention of such behavior in Apple docs, though some other dudes mentioned it in forums. Any reference will be gladly accepted.

Thanks.

Comment: I would almost consider it implicitly documented for taking a key *path* as opposed to just a *key*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not just that you'll get a change notification if the `controller` property changes, it's that KVO will switch to tracking the `isEnabled` property of the new controller and stop tracking the `isEnabled` property of the old controller.

This is implicit in the notion of a key path. Key-Value Observing is built on top of Key-Value Coding. The Key-Value Coding Programming Guide says this about key paths in [Key-Value Coding Fundamentals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html):

> A key path is a string of dot separated keys that is used to specify a sequence of object properties to traverse. The property of the first key in the sequence is relative to the receiver, and each subsequent key is evaluated relative to the value of the previous property.
>
> For example, the key path `address.street` would get the value of the `address` property from the receiving object, and then determine the `street` property relative to the `address` object.

The meaning of `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` is not "follow the key path to the final element and observe that property on the second-to-last object". It's "observe this key path of the receiver object". The key path is always considered starting from the receiver.

Put another way, for your second code example, it's not "observe the `isEnabled` property of the `controller` of `self`" (that's the meaning of your first example). The meaning is "observe the `controller.isEnabled` of `self`. Any time that the result of evaluating the expression `[self valueForKeyPath:@"controller.isEnabled"]` has or might have changed, notify me."

> I know it works but should I use it?

Yes, you should use it. It's the intended meaning of the API. It's why the method describes its parameter as a key **path** rather than just a key.

Comment: _"It's not just that you'll get a change notification if the controller property changes, it's that KVO will switch to tracking the isEnabled property of the new controller and stop tracking the isEnabled property of the old controller"_.

Thanks for clarifying this matter, however I am still feeling some what uncomfortable with the fact that this is not explicitly documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> on the second approach i will get a notification if the 'controller'
>   object on self was replaced

I would rephrase by saying that on the second approach you'll get notified if the controller object gets replaced **or if its `isEnabled` property changes**. In other word when `controller.isEnabled` changes (as explained by Ken's answer).

Check this example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.controller = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

    [self.controller addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isEnabled" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"controller.isEnabled" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.controller.isEnabled = !self.controller.isEnabled;

        // replace controller
        [self.controller removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isEnabled"];
        self.controller = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.controller.isEnabled = !self.controller.isEnabled;
        });
    });
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"KVO %d %@ %p", self.controller.isEnabled, keyPath, self.controller);
}
```

We'll get 4 KVO notifications:

```
KVO 1 controller.isEnabled 0x7fbbc2e4b4e0 <-- These 2 fire together when we toggle isEnbled
KVO 1 isEnabled 0x7fbbc2e4b4e0            <-- So basically 1. and 2. behave the same
KVO 0 controller.isEnabled 0x7fbbc2e58d30 <---- controller was replaced
KVO 1 controller.isEnabled 0x7fbbc2e58d30 <---- Toggle on the new instance
```